# Flutter is not clearing rendered widgets, only re-painting

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-inappwebview

I am having a Scaffold with a `floatingActionButton`. Inside I have an [inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) which displays some webpage. The `floatingActionButton` is displayed in the front above the webview. Also I show some dialog for a second.

Everything worked fine until yesterday. I upgraded flutter and I suddenly experienced weird behaviour which is why i downgraded flutter again. But I still got the same problem. All the stuff that is rendered above is never cleared and just re-painted all the time, which leads to dark shadows and never disappearing dialog windows.

[image]

Here you can see the dark shadow around the `floatingActionButton` and the `bottomBar`. Also the "<3 + Karma" badge does not disappear anymore.

The weird thing is, that I did not change anything. On my other machine everything still builds fine. There I use the same code, same package versions in my `pubspec.yaml` and also the same flutter/dart version.

I am really puzzled here. I can't seem to build a new app version without this bug on my main desktop machine.

This is my currently used flutter version:

```
Flutter 2.10.2 • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision 097d3313d8 (3 months ago) • 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
Engine • revision a83ed0e5e3
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

`flutter doctor` tells me, `No issues found!`

This is my code for reference:

```
return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: ArticleHandler().backButtonPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: Visibility(
            visible: _fabIsVisible,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                webView.scrollTo(x: 0, y: 0, animated: true);
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_upward,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            )),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: MarginEndFloatFABLocation(),
        floatingActionButtonAnimator: NoFABAnimation(),
        appBar: TopBar(widget.articlePreview.url),
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              progress < 1.0
                  ? Container(
                      height: 3,
                      child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                        value: progress,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                      ))
                  : Container(height: 0),
              Expanded(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                          android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(useHybridComposition: true),
                          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                              //cacheEnabled: false, // uncomment this line to clean cache on open
                              )),
                      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                        webView = controller;
                      },
                      onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                        setState(() {
                          this.progress = progress / 100;
                        });
                      },
                      onOverScrolled: (InAppWebViewController controller, int x, int y, bool clampedX, bool clampedY) {
                        // maybe show karma badge
                      },
                      onScrollChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int x, int y) async {
                        if (y > 0) {
                          if (!_fabIsVisible) {
                            setState(() {
                              _fabIsVisible = true;
                            });
                          }
                        } else {
                          if (_fabIsVisible) {
                            setState(() {
                              _fabIsVisible = false;
                            });
                          }
                        }
                      })),
              BottomTagBar(),
            ],
          ));
        }),
      ));
```

Comment: does it happen too if you add `Container(color: Colors.white)` as a parent of `InAppWebView`?

Comment: yes, it does not change it @pskink

Comment: Can you try to remove `Visibility` widget and use `_fabIsVisible ? <widget> : undefined` insteads ?